# Keyframe animation not working with SVG... Trying to move the kid up, right, down on an angle, and back using transform. Is this possible?

Tags: css, animation, svg, keyframe

Below is the CSS to my project, I am attempting to move part of an SVG element which is in the HTML using SVG Code from Illustrator. The line in the HTML is

```
<g class="Kid">
```

This is the CSS Keyframes that I can't seem to get working...

```
@keyframes walking {


    25% {
        transform: translateY(225);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translateX(134);
    }

    75% {
        transform: translate3d(286, 225);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(-371);
    }

}

.Kid {
    animation: walking 10s infinite linear;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The transforms are applied individually, not cumulatively.  So you need to provide X and Y coordinates for each stage.

- The up direction is -Y. You were going the wrong way.
- You should provide units for the coordinates.

```css
svg {
    background-color: linen;
}

.Kid {
    animation: walking 10s infinite linear;
}


@keyframes walking {

    25% {
        transform: translate(0px, -225px);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translate(134px, -225px);
    }

    75% {
        transform: translate(286px, -100px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0px ,0px);
    }

}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <rect x="50" y="350" width="20" height="20" fill="red" class="Kid"/>
</svg>
```